# Cleanest way to copy a constant size array in c++11

Tags: c++, arrays, optimization, c++11, copy

I often find myself wanting to copy the contents of arrays that have a constant size, I usually just write something along the lines of:

```
float a[4] = {0,1,2,3};
float b[4];

for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    b[i]=a[i];
}
```

As of lately, I am writing a linear calculus library for educational purposes, and I was wondering if there was a better way to do it.

The first thing that came to my mind, was using memcpy:

```
memcpy(b, a, sizeof(float) * 4);
```

But this seems very c-like and error prone to me. I like having my errors at compile time, and this can get ugly for data types with non-trivial copy constructors, or if I forget to multiply with sizeof(datatype).

Since I am writing a math library that I am going to use intensively, performance is very important to me. Are the compilers today smart enough to understand that the first example is just copying a chunk of memory and optimize it to be as efficient as the second solution?

Perhaps there is a function in the standard library that can help me? Something new in c++11? Or should I just create a macro or a template function?

Comment: *"But this seems very c-like and error prone to me"* - What's error prone about it? You know the size, you know the memory is valid... no error will occur. If you are dealing with POD types I would always just use `memcpy`.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

If you use `std::array` instead of a built-in array (which you should), it becomes very simple.  Copying an array is then the same as copying any other object.

```
std::array<float,4> a = {0,1,2,3};
std::array<float,4> b = a;
```

Comment: +1 this is clearly the way to go in C++11 (and not the `std::copy()` methods, as they use run-time size and hence are less prone to optimisation using than compile-time size, which is the very point of using arrays (instead of `vector`) in the first place

Comment: @Walter: Actually, the methods using `std::copy`, as presented by Mysticial and hjbabs, both use a compile time constant.  So they can be optimized in the exact same ways.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley you didn't get my point. The `std::copy()` function template accepts the size as a *run-time constant*. If that number is known at compile time, then the compiler *may* do some optimisation. With `std::array<>::operator=` this is spelled out at compile time: there is not run-time-size-dependent code to be optimised (or not). I prefer not relying on the compiler to do these types of optimisations.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  This question is about C style arrays.  Why is the solution using std::arrays?  To me this should definitely NOT be the canonical answer to the question.

Comment: @user650261: The question is not about C-style arrays. It is about constant sized arrays. One way to have a constant size array is to use a c-style array. Another way, which the OP apparently was not aware of before asking the question, is `std::array`. And as it turns out, `std::array` is superior for that purpose, in almost every single way. And in particular, it is much better at solving the very problem the OP was actually concerned about.

Answer (score 58):

**The C++03 way**

Use [`std::copy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/):

```
float a[4] = {0,1,2,3};
float b[4];

std::copy(a,a + 4, b);
```

That's about as clean as it gets.

**The C++11 way**

```
std::copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(b));
```

**If you can use std::array**

With `std::array` you just do simple assignment:

```
std::array<float,4> a = {0,1,2,3};
auto b = a;
```

Comment: To avoid things quietly breaking if you change the array size, I suggest `std::copy(a, a + sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]), b);`.  Even better, wrap the `sizeof()` junk in a macro -- or even betterer, use a function template instead: `template <typename T, size_t N> size_t size((T&)[N]) { return N; }`

Comment: @j_random_hacker: In C++11, `std:copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(b))`.

Comment: @GManNickG: So they finally added generic `begin()` and `end()` in C++11?  Wonderful!  (And such an obvious thing...  How did C++03 miss it?!)  I can stop carting around my homebrewed ones :)

Comment: Interesting. I also didn't know you could use `std::begin/end` on arrays now. :)

Comment: Downvoters care to comment? It's hard to improve something if I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: I think it might have been the use of magic numbers as commented before. I have edited to reflect the comment thread

Comment: Thanks for edit. I wasn't sure if it was right to take it from the comments.

Comment: @Mysticial I couldn't get `std::copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(b));` to work on an array of `int` primitives and on the latest version of g++ using C++14 standard. Instead I had to use your first recommendation, `std::copy(a, a + x, b);` and that worked.

Comment: People downvoting because there is no copy of `std::array`, it's an assignment ctor -> answer is not correct.

Answer (score 22):

For interested in C++03 (and also C) solution - always use struct containing an array instead of solely array:

```
struct s { float arr[5]; };
```

Structs are copyable by default.

Its equivalent in C++11 is,already mentioned, `std::array<float,5>;`

Comment: Good point about c++03 struct wrapping. I need to remember this better :)

Comment: thank you this is the info i was looking for from google. Because nothing much is said about assignation of std/boost::array. its default generated, therefore the standard dictates behavior. but chapters about aggregate are hard to read in santardese legal jargon.

Answer (score 7):

Below method works for usual arrays as well std:array.

```
float a[4] = {0,1,2,3};
float b[4];

std::copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), b);
```

Comment: Note sure why downvoting. This works, its indeed preferred way in C++, applicable to usual arrays as well and I use it all the time.

Comment: @Shitai Shah, preferred or not it's ugly and easy to error prone.

Comment: @CodingLab, disagree.  My code is littered with this and it is a fine solution if you are using c-style arrays which are abundant out there in the real world.

Comment: How can this be uglier than `std::array<float,4> a = {0,1,2,3};` ?  I prefer this and use it in both C and C++. Looks cool and simple.  Unfortunately, older c++ versions (< C++11) don't support this for member initialisation within class declarations.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <algorithm>
std::copy_n(a, 4, b)
```

Comment: that can't be the most efficient way in case of arrays, as the number of elements is a run-time argument instead of a compile-time one.

Comment: @Walter: you are right, std::array should be used for constant size arrays

Comment: @Walter All answers here depend on quality of compiler inliner and memcpy intrinsic. copy_n here will probably transformed to one SIMD instruction.

Comment: @Walter see https://godbolt.org/z/76nh7hbTh

Comment: > that can't be the most efficient way 
was not the question. The question was > Cleanest way to copy... given an otherwise unspecified _constant size array_. So this is a perfectly valid answer. It is also much easier to read than `std::copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), b);`