# Passing a 2D array into a function by reference

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I know that there are multiple answers on this particular subject but I am yet to find something that works for my use case.

I have a 2D array (9x9) that I need to pass into a function by reference so that it can be stored in the main program after the function is done with it.

Here is the function declaration:

```
void ReadFile(ifstream& infile, string fileName, string filePath, int array[9][9]) // Opens, reads, outputs and closes the file
```

The file I am opening is a 9x9 grid of numbers, I need to store that grid into a local variable (9x9 array of integers) within main.

Anybody know how I can go about this?

James

Comment: This is C++, use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead.

Comment: The answer is "Yes."

Comment: What keeps you from passing a reference? The function declaration would be `void ReadFile(ifstream& infile, string fileName, string filePath, int (&array)[9][9]);` (note the `&` before `array`; parentheses are necessary to avoid an -- impossible and unwanted -- array of references).

Answer (score 2):

I would drop the C-style array in favor of the C++ [std::array](http://fr.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), if you have access to C++11 features:

```
#include <array>

using Array = std::array<std::array<int, 9> 9>;

void ReadFile(ifstream& infile, string fileName, string filePath, const Array& array);
```

Then in your function, you can [copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328301/cleanest-way-to-copy-a-constant-size-array-in-c11) this array like any other variable. You also get all sorts of goodies, like the `size()` method, and iterator access. From cppreference (see link above):

> The struct combines the performance and accessibility of a C-style
>   array with the benefits of a standard container, such as knowing its
>   own size, **supporting assignment**, random access iterators, etc.